# Wrong credentials cause sign in alert box

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have react frontend and django backend. I am seeing an alert box when I enter incorrect credentials on my login screen.

[image]

On Google Chrome if I inspect the network requests, I see the login network call in pending state.

I have checked in postman that the login request fails as expected without causing any pending states.
Following is the code I have in react for login functionality,

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', usernameRef.current.value);
        formData.append('password', pwdRef.current.value);
        const axiosInstance = getAxiosInstance();
        console.log(`${TAG} Handling submit button`);
        cleanup();
        axiosInstance.post(loginUrlRef.current, formData)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(`${TAG}  response ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
                console.log(`${TAG} Error is ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    window.location.href='/';
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(`${TAG} Error ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
                setErrorMsg(INVALID_CREDENTIALS);
            }).finally(() => {
                event.target.reset();
            });
    };
```

[image]

When I click on 'Cancel' button on the dialog, I see 401 error (as expected since invalid credentials were entered) i.e. the request is getting blocked somehow. Am I missing anything? Why am I seeing this dialog?

Let me know if more information is needed.